# change the default blue color of animations in Hover.css

Tags: html, css, hover

How can I change the default blue color of animations in [Hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)

for instance in Border Transitions, the Underline From Center effect with orange

Answer (score 1):

This should work, overwrite (add to existing) class:

```
.hvr-underline-from-center::before {
    background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code Color All Hover.css  into Orange

```
[class^="hvr-"]::before {
    background: orange;
}
```